Which stones cannot become tamei (ritually impure)?
I understand that the Cohanim used to use stone ceilim (vessels) because stone ceilim cannot receive tumah (become ritually impure). But this begs the question what is a stone for this purpose? Can iron ceilim can become tameh? Does iron ore qualify as a stone? What about crystal quartz? What about gemstones in general? How do we define a stone according to the halacha?

I understand there's a line we have to draw between iron and iron ore, but I don't understand what is unclear about gemstones.

One read of mKeilim 11:3 is that iron ore keilim are tahor.

@magicker72 thanks. So what is the general principle here? What ingredient exactly makes the iron ore a stone but pure iron not?

@JamesRead The general principle is that גולמי כלי מתכות (unfinished metal utensils) are pure, because metal utensils aren't susceptible until they're finished. But you're asking about something that is finished but not in the way metal utensils normally are. So I don't know.

@JamesRead Also to be clear, it's not that something has to be a stone utensil to be insusceptible — that's just an example of utensils that are insusceptible. Whether iron ore falls in the category of stone is interesting, but it's not the only way iron ore utensils might be considered insusceptible (eg. if they're considered "unfinished").

The big question is what is metal? Obviously the definitions are not based on modern chemistry or the Table of the Elements, but how those terms were used in Biblical times.
